# How can I generate only indexes from a database into a sql file in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database that has indexes and the same copy of this database without indexes. How can i generate only indexes from my original database and import them into copy database?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

Task -> Generate Scripts -> Select specific database objects -> Tables. 
Then in Advanced select `Indexes` and unselect others. 
Also you need to select `Include if NOT EXISTS`, so when executing the script sql-server will not create tables which already exist.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but it generates the create tables too. I don't need that, i need just generating the create index script